# jqGrid. Animate hide/show columns

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

How to animate hide/show columns?

```
$("#button").toggle(
    function() {
        $('#data').jqGrid('hideCol',['col1','col2','col3']);
        // $("bla-bla").animate({
            // width: 100
        // }, 1000 );
    },
    function() {
        $('#data').jqGrid('showCol',['col1','col2','col3']);
        // $("bla-bla").animate({
            // width: 0
        // }, 1000 );
    }
);
```

[image: desired behaviour]

Is it possible?

We have many columns. Perhaps there is another way to fit all columns in one screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is easily possible without changing some internal jqgrid behaviors.
You could use combinations of `autowidth` `forceFit` and `shrinkToFit` to make the grid use the maximum available screen real estate and resize the columns so they all get some of the available space proportionally.

Comment: Why can't we just have the columns off screen and use a scroll-bar to view them?  That is what happened in DataTables